# How to create this type of json

Tags: json, django, python-3.x

I have a tuple like

```
mytuple = ('somevalue', 99999, 'jjj', 99)
```

from this tuple I want to make json like

```
{
"key1":'somevalue',
"key2":'99999,
"key3":'jjj',
"key4":99
}
```

the number of keys are not constant they can change and also value and  number of keys are equal to number of objects

I tried as

```
data = {}
        for i in range(0,maxLen):
            key = keydata[0][i]
            value = valuedata[0][i]
            data[key] = data[value]
```

I am getting key error while creating json

Comment: Please show `keydata` and `valuedata`

Comment: Please show your stack trace

Comment: Did you mean `data[key] = value`?

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: Your JSON is not valid JSON since JSON strings use double quotes, see https://json.org

Comment: yes data[key] = value  where value is inside multiple tuples where tuple is in list

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate(..)` to obtain the index. We can thus construct a dictionary like:

```
{ 'key{}'.format(i): v for i, v in enumerate(mytuple, 1) }
```

We can then use `json.dumps` to retrieve the JSON blob:

```
>>> json.dumps({ 'key{}'.format(i): v for i, v in enumerate(mytuple, 1) }) 
'{"key1": "somevalue", "key2": 99999, "key3": "jjj", "key4": 99}'
```

Note that the JSON you provided is not valid JSON, since a JSON string i surrounded by double quotes (so `"…"`), and furthermore your `99999` has a single quote (`'`) in front. You can validate this with a service like [*jsonlint*](https://jsonlint.com/) for example. A valid JSON blob is for example:

```
{
    "key1": "somevalue",
    "key2": 99999,
    "key3": "jjj",
    "key4": 99
}
```

This is the same as the one constructed here, except for the formatting, but that is, when you for example fetch data, only overhead.

Comment: still not getting result as expected. I have list and inside that list I have tuple which contains keys and value tuple i have provided in question

Comment: @alhkjsd: then you only need to make a functor mapping of the above, but since you do not provide the format of the real data, I'm afraid I can not help you more :).