# How to build json like this

Tags: json, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I want to build json something like this

```
{
        "meta":[
            {
              "key1": 12345,
              "key2": "berlin",
              "key3": "best place",
              "key4": 58
            },
            {
              "key1": 6789,
              "key2": "bangldesh",
              "key3": "great place",
              "key4": 58
            }
        ]
      }
```

I am getting data for that in a list called mylist. mylist may have n size

```
<class 'list'>: [('berlin', 12345, 'best place', 58), ('bangldesh', 6789, 'great place', 58)]
```

I also have keys variable as keylist. keylist may con be of n size

```
<class 'list'>: [('key1',), ('key2',), ('key3',), ('key4',)]
```

I tried to build json as

```
     count = 0
            for i in range(0,maxLen):
                key = keylist[count][0]
                value = mylist[0][count]
                data[key] = value
                print(data)
                count = count + 1
            jsonResult = json.dumps(data)
```

I am getting name error

Comment: How is this not just a duplicate of [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57833555/how-to-create-this-type-of-json)? The structures are only *trivially* different.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I would see it as an `fmap` variant, and it seems lifted with arbitrary column names.

Comment: Thank you so much Williem Van Onsem. It is working exactly as expected

Answer (score 0):

You can zip here;

```
data = [('berlin', 12345, 'best place', 58), ('bangldesh', 6789, 'great place', 58)]
keys = [('key1',), ('key2',), ('key3',), ('key4',)]

result = [ {k: v for (k,), v in zip(keys, sub)} for sub in data ]
```

we can create a JSON blob with:

```
json.dumps([ {k: v for (k,), v in zip(keys, sub)} for sub in data ])
```

For the sample data, this gives us:

```
>>> json.dumps([ {k: v for (k,), v in zip(keys, sub)} for sub in data ])
'[{"key1": "berlin", "key2": 12345, "key3": "best place", "key4": 58}, {"key1": "bangldesh", "key2": 6789, "key3": "great place", "key4": 58}]'
```

we can wrap it in a `{"meta": … }` with:

```
>>> json.dumps({'meta': [ {k: v for (k,), v in zip(keys, sub)} for sub in data ]})
'{"meta": [{"key1": "berlin", "key2": 12345, "key3": "best place", "key4": 58}, {"key1": "bangldesh", "key2": 6789, "key3": "great place", "key4": 58}]}'
```